# Integer overflow in Python3

Tags: python, integer, integer-overflow

I'm new to Python, I was reading [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/doctest.html#module-doctest) page where I saw a weird statement:

```
if n+1 == n:  # catch a value like 1e300
    raise OverflowError("n too large")
```

x equals to a number greater than it?! I sense a disturbance in the Force.

I know that in Python 3, integers don't have fixed byte length. Thus, there's no integer overflow, like how C's `int` works. But of course the memory can't store infinite data.

I think that's why the result of `n+1` can be the same as `n`: Python can't allocate more memory to preform the summation, so it is skipped, and `n == n` is true. Is that correct?

If so, this could lead to incorrect result of the program. Why don't Python raise an error when operations are not possible, just like C++'s `std::bad_alloc`?

Even if `n` is not too large and the check evaluates to false, `result` - due to the multiplication - would need much more bytes. Could `result *= factor` fail for the same reason?

I found it in the offical Python documentation. Is it really the correct way to check big integers / possible integer "overflow"?

Comment: n == n is true. I assume you mean n == (n+1)

Comment: That code doesn't actually catch large `int`s like 1e300. The int would have to be seriously huge for that to happen due to memory reasons. It does catch floats though, for the obvious reason. n must be a float.

Comment: @E.Serra No, I don't. I meant if the summation in `n    (+1)` is skipped, it may see and work with only `(n) (==) (n)`.

Comment: @Denziloe Indeed, my bad. We often use 'e' for integers too in math, but in Python we may use the `**` operator to get large integers.

Comment: Well, this function in the docs catches `1e16`, but accepts `10 ** 5000000` which is bad I think, because `1e16 < 10 ** 50` so that check is only for float inputs (there is no implicit conversion).

Answer (score 45, accepted):

### Python3

Only floats have
a hard limit in python. Integers [are implemented as “long” integer objects of arbitrary size in python3](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/long.html#integer-objects) and [do not normally overflow](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#OverflowError).

You can test that behavior with the following code

```
import sys

i = sys.maxsize
print(i)
# 9223372036854775807
print(i == i + 1)
# False
i += 1
print(i)
# 9223372036854775808

f = sys.float_info.max
print(f)
# 1.7976931348623157e+308
print(f == f + 1)
# True
f += 1
print(f)
# 1.7976931348623157e+308
```

You may also want to take a look at [sys.float_info](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.float_info) and [sys.maxsize](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.maxsize)

### Python2

In python2 integers are automatically casted to long integers if too large as described in the [documentation for numeric types](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#numeric-types-int-float-long-complex)

```
import sys

i = sys.maxsize
print type(i)
# <type 'int'>

i += 1
print type(i)
# <type 'long'>
```

> Could `result *= factor` fail for the same reason?

Why not try it?

```
import sys

i = 2
i *= sys.float_info.max
print i
# inf
```

Python has a special float value for infinity (and negative infinity too) as described in [the docs for float](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#float)

Comment: I accepted your answer because it gives a reverence to `MemoryError` (I didn't know about it) which is raised if I'd try to work with too big integers.

Comment: Btw my 3rd question is for big integers, not small (in bits) floats. Working with a number with more than 100k digits is not something I want to try out. :) It's enough to know how it would work in theory.

Answer (score 9):

I had a problem of with integer overlflows in python3, but when I inspected the types, I understood the reason:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([3095693933], dtype=int)
s = np.sum(a)
print(s)
# 3095693933
s * s
# -8863423146896543127
print(type(s))
# numpy.int64
py_s = int(s)
py_s * py_s
# 9583320926813008489
```

Some pandas and numpy functions, such as `sum` on arrays or Series return an np.int64 so this might be the reason you are seeing int overflows in Python3.

Answer (score 8):

Integers don't work that way in Python.

But float does. That is also why the comment says `1e300`, which is a float in scientific notation.