# Getting inaccurate results from Python big number computation

Tags: python

I used `Python 3.9.4 (default, Apr  5 2021, 01:50:46)`.

The result of `2**256 - 2**224 + 2**192 - 2*96 - 1` should be `115792089210356248762697446949407573530086143415290314195533631308867097853951`.
However, if you try it in the Python REPL, you get something wrong.

```
>>> 2**256 - 2**224 + 2**192 + 2*96 - 1
115792089210356248762697446949407573530086143415211086033019366971273553903807
```

I can check the correct output by subtracting it piece by piece.

```
>>> x = 115792089210356248762697446949407573530086143415290314195533631308867097853951
>>> x -= 2**256
>>> x
-26959946660873538059280334323183841250350249843923952699046031785985
>>> x += 2**224
>>> x -= 2**192
>>> x
79228162514264337593543950335
>>> x -= 2**96
>>> x
-1
```

Can anybody explain what's happening here?

Comment: For those who is curious what is this big number, it is the prime number from NIST P-256 curve in FIPS 186-4.

Comment: That looks like a typo of `2*96` rather than `2**96`. I am voting to close it as such.

Comment: Yes, this was a typo. I should peer check with someone others before asking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a typo

```
2**256 + ... -  2*96 - 1
```

Should be

```
2**256 + ... -  2**96 - 1
```

Normally [Integer overflows do not happen in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52151647/integer-overflow-in-python3). There are float overflows.