# How can Python represent 2**500 as an int?

Tags: python

What type of `int` is the result of this calculation? Why isn't there a numerical overflow issue?

```
>>> 2**500
3273390607896141870013189696827599152216642046043064789483291368096133796404674554883270092325904157150886684127560071009217256545885393053328527589376
>>> type(2**500)
<class 'int'>
```

Comment: Because python `int` objects are arbitrarily sized, as long as you have memory and address space, you are good

Comment: Don't confuse Python's `int` type with whatever integer types your hardware supports. A Python `int` is really like a resizable array of base-2**30 digits (or something like that).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy certainly I don't think it's unique to 2**500. In fact I experimented with `2**501` and the result was similar

Comment: My meaning was that this is not unique to `**`.

Comment: Can you clarify your question? The type of the calculation is... ``int``. As your example shows.

Comment: I was being facetious. Thanks for the input! @CharlesDuffy

Comment: with 501 bits...? :p

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I believe the "Why isn't there a numerical overflow issue?" says it all Hence the accepted answer

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How Python is working with a number bigger than the 64-bit unsigned integer limit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63922356/how-python-is-working-with-a-number-bigger-than-the-64-bit-unsigned-integer-limi)

Comment: @MisterMiyagi it also does, yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52151647/integer-overflow-in-python3)
"In Python, integers are implemented as “long” integer objects of arbitrary size", they do not overflow
https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/long.html#integer-objects

Answer (score 1):

I think this is implemented as a `bignum` which can handle arbitrarily large integer. You can find a more detailed discussion here, [Handling very large numbers in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/538551/handling-very-large-numbers-in-python)